# Why is my resolver not returning the first time?

Tags: javascript, mongoose, graphql, apollo

I am building a GraphQL server and getting some weird behaviour with one of my resolvers. The first time I run the mutation it returns null, but when I use logging the console clearly shows that the object has been returned by Mongoose before I attempt to return it.

Resolver:

```
setView(error, { name, author, data }) {
    if (error) return console.error(error);
    console.log(`Creating new view named: ${name}`);
    let newView = new View({ name: name, author: author, data: data });
    newView.save();
    console.log("View created");
    console.log(View.findOne({ name: name }));
    return View.findOne({ name: name });
}
```

Console log:

> Creating new view named: testView5
>
> View created
>
> model.Query {_mongooseOptions: Object, mongooseCollection:
>   NativeCollection, model: , schema: Schema, op: "findOne", …}
>
> Creating new view named: testView5
>
> View created
>
> model.Query {_mongooseOptions: Object, mongooseCollection:
>   NativeCollection, model: , schema: Schema, op: "findOne", …}

Mutation:

```
mutation {
  setView(
    name: "testView7",
    author: "Bob", 
    data: [
        "First Column", 
        "Second Column", 
        "Third Column"
    ]) {
    name
  }
}
```

Initial return:

```
{
  "data": {
    "setView": null
  }
}
```

Subsequent return (same mutation run again):

```
{
  "data": {
    "setView": {
      "name": "testView7"
    }
  }
}
```

Currently, I am wondering if it is something to do with how I am returning with findOne but I can't understand what it could be if it works the second time.

Comment: if its a new item you have to pass {new: true } for it to return the new item

Comment: Unless I am missing something that is for findOneAndUpdate, not for findOne.

Comment: yeah fair well save is a async action so i assume doc wasnt saved when you ran find

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Joe Warner was correct above when he said that save is asynchronous. The solution was to make the function await the promise from save as below:

```
    async setView(error, { name, author, data }) {
        if (error) return console.error(error);
        console.log(`Creating new view named: ${name}`);
        let newView = new View({ name: name, author: author, data: data });
        var result = await newView.save();
        console.log(`Created view: ${result}`);
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: glad to help  :)